# How to play image slideshow in another image?

Tags: html, css

I have got a laptop image with blank screen and I want to play an image slideshow in it. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This shouldn't be too difficult with either JS or CSS animation. Give it a go yourself and see what you can come up with, then ask if you hit any specific problems.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far. No one is here to do someone else job/homework rather to help good programmers who  have trouble doing something.

Comment: _“Please help ASAP.”_ – please ditch that attitude – ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your `slideshow div` in it(laptop image with blank screen). and in slideshow div you can put images and can slide them using js as well as jquery. whichever you want.

eg.

this is your laptop screen div.

```
<div id="laptop_div">
// now put slideshow div in this div
   <div id="slideshow">
        <img src ="your image path" width="your image width" height="your image height"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

after that create slideshow for the div.